# Bucle con fechas

Tags: date, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark

Estoy intentando crear un bucle que se encargue de leer un df particionado por fecha. Este df solo está particionado por los días hábiles del mes, por lo que si yo intento leer la tabla un 30 o 31 del mes que cae en sabado/domindo me dará un error de que no hay info.

¿Hay alguna forma de crear un bucle que se encargue de leer el df empezando por el último día del mes y recorrer los días hacia atrás hasta dar con el día que sí puede leer ese particionado?

Ej.: Si el 30/06/2022 cae un sabado, entonces que pase al al 29/06/2022 que es viernes y si que hay información en el df para leer.

Muchas gracias de ante mano

Comment: He intentado algo así: 

while True:
   try: .read(path+fecha)
        break
    except:
        fecha-1

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya lo he conseguido. Me refería a algo asi (por si es de ayuda a alguien más):

```
#Creación de Cutoff Date para casos especiales Días Habiles

from datetime import datetime

lastBusDay = datetime.strptime(DATA_DATE, "%Y-%m-%d")

import datetime

if datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) == 5: #Si es Sábado
    lastBusDay = lastBusDay - datetime.timedelta(days = 1) #Entonces devuelve día anterior hábil

elif datetime.date.weekday(lastBusDay) == 6: #Si es Domingo
    lastBusDay = lastBusDay - datetime.timedelta(days = 2); #Entonces devuelve día anterior hábil
    
DATA_DATE_BD = lastBusDay.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```